# Import Error: cannot import name get_importer

Tags: python, linux, buildroot

I'm trying to run the scanpypi script - support script of the Buildroot (2017.02) but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./support/scripts/scanpypi", line 52, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pkgutil import get_importer
ImportError: cannot import name get_importer
```

I added the following lines into beginning of the scanpypi script to see sys.path

```
- import sys
- print(sys.path)
```

output:

```
['/home/timo/bldr_lab/buildroot/support/scripts', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

As the pkgutil is in the /usr/lib/python2.7 directory the problem is not path problem.

I have also uninstalled and re-installed python2.7, pip and setuptools but no help.

What could be reason for the ImportError?

Comment: What happens if you `python -c 'import pkgutil; print(pkgutil.__file__)`?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. I've tried to debug it with `pudb` but in the debugger it works like a charm. I've tried `scanpypi` on different Linux distros and all show the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Buildroot. It is due to commit 12683184b1969f65680cb7db55b547a620a9860f that introduced the `pkgutil.py` file in support/scripts. This conflicts with the `pkgutil.py` from setuptools.

The solution is to rename the `pkgutil.py` file to something else, and update the imports in the other scripts accordingly. If you do this, please post a patch on [the Buildroot mailing list](http://lists.busybox.net/mailman/listinfo/buildroot), so everyone can benefit. See [the manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#submitting-patches) for details how to post patches.

Comment: Thanks for info. I actually noticed that "pkgutil.py" is in the support/scripts folder today morning. I renamed it and then scanpypi script started to work as expected.

Comment: I just left then wondered why the pkgutil.py was in the folder but now I know.  Somehow I'm thinking that reporting a bug would be the correct way to get the problem fixed - I'm bit reluctant to touch other's code. Anyway, I'll try to look at this later today.